# Putting a rss feed into a dynamic page asynchronously - wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, rss

On my wordpress site I have a number of dynamic pages based around different people. I do an Ajax call to get the data, generate all the html with the data included in a javascript function, then insert it all into a div on the actual page. With this, I want to show the most recent three articles about the specific person the page has loaded for. I've found results telling me to add this to functions.php:

```
//This file is needed to be able to use the wp_rss() function.
include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php');
function readRss($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "feed" => 'http://',
      "num" => '1',
    ), $atts));

    return wp_rss($feed, $num);
}
add_shortcode('rss', 'readRss');
```

So then I tried to put this in my html:

```
var rsser = '<h2>In the News</h2>' +
            '[rss feed="http://website.com/tag/' + tagname + '/feed/" num="3"]';
$('#rssCon').html(rsser);
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working and I'm afraid it might be because it's happening asynchronously. "tagname" in this case would be a piece of data I got from the Ajax call.

So what I'm looking for is a way to dynamically generate the rss feed asynchronously. If it's possible it'd be great if someone could point my in a good direction, or, if it's not, let me know!

Adding more code:

```
var getNewsPerson = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://website/api/v1/api?pid=" + personId,
        type:"get",
        success:function(res) {
            return_tagname(res);
            processPerson(res);
        }
    });
};

function processPerson(data) {
    var returnedFeedShortcode = return_tagname(data);
    var head = 
        '<div class="headForPerson-nt">' +
            '<div class="hfpm-NextPerson-nt">' +
                '<div class="hfpm-header-nt">' + data[0][0].FirstName + '</div>' +
                '<div class="hfpm-ng-one-nt">' + data[0][0].LastName + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="hfpm-News-nt">' +
                '<div class="hfpm-header-nt">In the News</div>' + returnedFeedShortcode +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    $('#personPageHead-nt').html(head);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#personPageHead-nt').length) {
        getNewsPerson(location.search);
    }
});

function return_tagname(data) {
    var tagname = data[0][0].FirstName + '+' + data[0][0].LastName;
    return do_shortcode('[rss feed="http://website/tag/' + tagname + '/feed/" num="3"]');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the shortcode via javascript isn't going to work. It won't be processed since the PHP has already run on the page. You will need to process the shortcode via the AJAX call and return that HTML to the javascript function instead of the tagname.

The following are your javascript calls. You shouldn't have do_shortcode in here. It is a PHP call that needs to be in your functions.php file which I'll show after.

```
var getNewsPerson = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://website/api/v1/api?pid=" + personId,
        type:"get",
        success:function(res) {
            processPerson(res);
        }
    });
};

function processPerson(data) {
    var returnedFeedShortcode = return_tagname(data);
    var head = 
        '<div class="headForPerson-nt">' +
            '<div class="hfpm-NextPerson-nt">' +
                '<div class="hfpm-header-nt">' + data[0][0].FirstName + '</div>' +
                '<div class="hfpm-ng-one-nt">' + data[0][0].LastName + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="hfpm-News-nt">' +
                '<div class="hfpm-header-nt">In the News</div>' + returnedFeedShortcode +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    $('#personPageHead-nt').html(head);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#personPageHead-nt').length) {
        getNewsPerson(location.search);
    }
});

function return_tagname(data) {
    var tagname = data[0][0].FirstName + '+' + data[0][0].LastName;
    var requestData = {
        'action': 'return_tagname',
        'tagname': tagname
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: requestData,
        success: function( tagdata ) {
            return tagdata;
    }
})
};
```

Here is what needs to be added in your functions.php file:

```
//You need to do this when enqueuing your javascript so that you have access to the Wordpress AJAX URL. The contents of this function can be added to your current function that is enqueuing your styles and scripts.
function my_enqueue_script(){
    // declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_script' );

//The 'action data ('return_tagname') sent in the ajax call will tell Wordpress to use this function. You need to have it end in _callback.
function return_tagname_callback(){
    //$_POST['tagname'] is coming from the AJAX post made in the return_tagname function on the javascript side. do_shortcode will return the result of the function.
    return do_shortcode('[rss feed="http://website/tag/' + $_POST['tagname'] + '/feed/" num="3"]');
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'return_tagname_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'return_tagname_callback' );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "process the shortcode via the AJAX call". I created return_tagname() and put what it returned into the html generated by the AJAX call, but I'm getting that "wp_rss is not defined" in the return statement of the function. I've tried using "do_shortcode" and "add_shortcode" as well but the code I added to functions.php seemed to say to use "wp_rss" so I went with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you're using AJAX you'll have to run do_shortcode in functions.php and return the value. The documentation you're using probably isn't using AJAX. Post the whole javascript part of the AJAX call to your question and I'll make sure that's correct.

Comment: Added. Without trying to add the rss feed all the other parts worked so I don't assume I have some error elsewhere that's messing it up but it's always possible.

Comment: This was very helpful. You are going to need another AJAX call to make this work. I'm traveling right now but will post a new answer this evening/night that will help.

Comment: I updated the answer. Since do_shortcode is PHP and not javascript you need to make a second AJAX call to run that function.

Comment: I apologize but I still can't get this working. I did a lot of reading on things you used before coming back for more help but can't seem to fix it. The error I'm seeing is simply that "MyAjax" is not defined in the javascript function. Therefore I assume either the localizing or enqueuing isn't happening properly.

However, I'm also getting a new error in the console about "A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script is invoked via a document.write." Since I only see these when I add the code to functions.php it could also be a part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

For RSS Feed you can use this. Paste It on your template-page.

```
    <?php
    $curl = 
    curl_init('http://website.com/tag/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $page = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
    {
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $regex = '/<table class="StoryengineTable">(.*?)<\/div>/s';
    if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
    else 
    print "Not found"; 
    ?>
```